# Unity netcode change player name

Tags: unity-game-engine

Currently I'm wanting to change the player's name when entering a room.
I below is the sample code. When a player enters the room, it will display Player1, player2, player3...

```
playerNetworkName.Value = "Player: " + OwnerClientId;
```

Now I want to allow users to change their name. I changed the code to

```
playerNetworkName.Value = UiManager.UserName;
```

But it doesn't work. The names of all players in the room will display according to the room owner's name
For example, if the room owner names it as abc, all other players will also display it as abc.
UserName is a static variable assigned to UiManager
We wish everyone help

```
private NetworkVariable<NetworkString> playerNetworkName = new NetworkVariable<NetworkString>();
 
private bool overlaySet = false;
 
public override void OnNetworkSpawn()
{
     if (IsServer)
     {
         // name = "Player: " + OwnerClientId;
         playerNetworkName.Value = "Player: " + OwnerClientId;
        // playerNetworkName.Value = UiManager.UserName;
     }
}
public void SetOverlay()
{
     Logger.Instance.LogWarning("SetOverlay");
     var localPlayerOverlay = gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshProUGUI>();
     localPlayerOverlay.text = $"{playerNetworkName.Value}";
 
}
public void Update()
{
     if (!overlaySet && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(playerNetworkName.Value))
     {
         SetOverlay();
         overlaySet = true;
     }
}
```

Comment: It probably should be a network variable so that the others transmit theirs but also only set from the entered one if its your player